# Rb-inotify can't tell when symlink changes

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, inotify

Here is the code:

```
require 'rb-inotify'

notifier = INotify::Notifier.new

notifier.watch("/path/to/folder", :moved_to, :create, :attrib, :modify) do |event|
   puts "I found #{event.name}!"
end

notifier.run
```

The folder is a symlink to another folder. I want to know when that symlink changes. For example I have `/path/to/folder -> /link1` and when it changes to `/path/to/folder -> /link2` I need to be able to tell. Currently I can change the underlying symlink and no events will be recorded. Is this possible using inotify or the ruby wrapper rb-inotify? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the flag `IN_DONT_FOLLOW` so that the symlink itself is watched, else it will watch `/link1`.

Comment: Once the symlink changes, it doesn't notice if the symlink changes again. I imagine this is expected behavior though.